# SpriteKit presentScene crash app

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit

I am navigating between SK scenes using the following code:

```
        SKScene *newScene = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size state:state];

        float duration = 1;

        SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:duration];

        [self.view presentScene:newScene transition:transition];
```

Regardless the type of scene I am trying to present, the app crashes every time with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 1) without any zombies.. It looks like the "present scene won't work correctly on xcode6, it did work before I upgraded from xcode5

---

edit: this is the initWithSize code:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size state:(GameState)state{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

    [self setupScene];

    if (state == GameStateLaunch) {

        [self setupLoadingScreen];

        [self switchToLaunch];

    } else if (state == GameStateTutorial || state == GameStateReplay) {

        [self switchToTutorial];

    } else if (state== GameStateMainMenu) {


        [self switchToMainMenu];
    }

}
    return self;
}
```

I managed to make it work partially by removing all children before presenting the new scene:

```
- (void)cleanUpChildrenAndRemove {
    for (SKNode *child in self.children) {
        [child removeFromParent];
    }
    [self removeFromParent];
}
```

However, this is crazy. There must be a better solution!

Comment: Could you post the initWithSize:state: method? What is the state object that is being passed?

Comment: Apparently a message is being sent to an object in your deallocated scene. Do you have anything outside of the scene interacting with the objects within it? Are you using NSTimer to send a message to a child node? Try using a exception breakpoint, it might help pinpoint which line exactly is causing the exception.

Comment: I do nothing with the new scene yet... its a simple transition that should work without issues.. I am currently running xcode6 + SpriteKit

Comment: It's not about the new scene, but the old one which you are transitioning from.

Comment: post the crash message, call stack / highlight line where crash occurs